# Angular2 ES5 - overriding Content-Type in HTTP POST header

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Trying to override content type for the header, but it's still coming at text/plain. There's a way to doit with Ben Nadel's GateWayAPI, but hoping there's a solution that doesn't involve custom wrapping.

```
    var url = this.url;
    var body = JSON.stringify({email_login: "login", password_login: "password"});
    var headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });


    return this.http.post(url, body, {headers:headers})
        .map(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request `post` of `Http` have the following signature:

```
post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs)
```

Third argument is parameter with type `RequestOptionsArgs`, which means you have to pass `RequestOptions` to it, not `Headers`. You also should use arrow operator (`=>`) instead of `function`. What you are looking for is something like this:

```
result: any;

httpPostTest() {

var url = this.url;
var body = JSON.stringify({email_login: "login", password_login: "password"});

let headers: Headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
let options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

this.http.post(url, body, options)
    .map(response => {
        response = response.json();
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

After this, you need to use subscribe to get `response`, so let's say that this function is called `httpPostTest` (I'll add it above) and we want to store response in variable called `result`:

```
this.httpPostTest().subscribe(
            response => { this.result = response; },
            error => { console.log('ERROR'); },
            () => { console.log('FINISHED')}
);
```

Comment: Tried it, get the following error:  EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: RequestOptions is not defined.<br/>For some reason, I create a new Headers() obj, but not a new RequestOptions() obj, even though both of them are available in Angular's http.umd.js file.<br/><br/>    app.TestService = function (http) {this.http = http;};<br/>app.TestService.parameters = [ ng.http.Http ];<br/>app.TestService.prototype.getData = function () {        var headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

Comment: @kaotik Did you import `RequestOptions`? Like this: `import { RequestOptions, Http, Headers } from "@angular/http";`

Comment: I'm using ES5, so I'm simply including http.umd.js in index.html.  Then I pass ng.http.httpModule and ng.http.Http to the component/service.  I believe the ng.htpp.Http already contains everything needed, since I can create an instance of Headers().  But I might be wrong.

Comment: It worked for me like a charm. Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1):

How about using the append function instead:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of the RequestOptions class and use strings instead of json objects as you are using form-urlencoded:

```
 var body = "email_login=login&password_login=password";
 var headers = new Headers();
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
 this.http.post(url, body, options);
```